# Using regex to find mid-sentence carriage returns

Tags: regex, replace

I am very new to regex, but so far liking it's power. Incredible, although a lot to get my head around.

I've been trying to figure this one out for a while now, testing various regular expressions based on what I'm reading online. But I seem to be missing something.

I have a long document in OpenOffice/LibreOffice. The author has used the following poor layout practices which I need to remove and/or rectify:

1) Spaces at the front of lines, used to indent a paragraph.

2) Spaces at the end of lines. No idea why they are there.

3) Carriage returns in the middle of sentences to force wrapping (I guess). I call these "fake CRs". Essentially any CR without sentence defining punctuation (a full stop, question mark, exclamation mark, or any of these with a " after it) is a "fake CR" in this situation. If there is appropriate sentence defining punctuation before the CR, then I consider this a genuine CR, and don't wish to remove it.

I have been able to do #1 and #2 easily enough. But #3 has me stumped.

I managed to hack together something that would find what I want, but it would include the last letter of the line rather than just the CR. So doing even an empty replace would get rid of the CR but ALSO the last letter.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The software I am using to execute this regex is TextSoap (on Mac). As far as I can tell it handles Regex is the "normal" way, as opposed to having its own irregular twist on it.

I would actually like to run the resulting Regex in Find-Replace on LibreOffice/OpenOffice but it doesn't accept any standard regex stuff I am throwing at it. They work fine in TextSoap, but turn up no results in OO/LO. Not sure why—seems OO does not have a default implementation of Regex (or I am just doing something wrong). So I am currently copying the text from LibreOffice document over to text soap, sorting it out, and copying it back.

Thank you...

Jonathan

UPDATE:
It would have been appropriate for me to provide an example (sorry for forgetting to do so):

There's a sample here:    http://best-mac-tips.com/wp-content/uploads/example.txt

Comment: Can you post an example sentence with this CR problem?

Comment: I would like to. But I am not sure how to get it to keep its exact formatting. The multiple spaces at the start of each line, and other oddities, are causing my example to be completely changed.

Comment: Okay... Here is a sample:
http://best-mac-tips.com/wp-content/uploads/example.txt

Comment: You could use rubular as a guide here possibly to fine tune things.... http://rubular.com/r/7i9G3Ld9gg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This regex for mid-sentence line breaks should work in TextMate:

```
(?<![\s.?!]"|[\s.?!])\s+
```

TM's regex functionality is supplied by the [Oniguruma library](http://www.geocities.jp/kosako3/oniguruma/doc/RE.txt), which will accept a lookbehind consisting of two or more alternatives with different but fixed lengths.  Or you can just use this, which should work in any flavor that supports lookbehinds:

```
(?<![\s.?!]")(?<![\s.?!])\s+
```

The replacement string would be a single space.  This will also replace simple spaces, but that won't harm anything.  To get rid of the leading and trailing spaces, use this regex:

```
^[ ]+|[ ]+$
```

...and replace it with nothing.  (The brackets aren't really necessary, they just make it easier to read.)

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing an example I think this would work to find any \n or \r  that's not end of sentence:

```
 (.+?)([\n\r]+)(.+?[\.\?\!]+)
```

Combining match group 1 and 3 with a space between would return the string you want, i suspect.

(Updated, because for some reason I had assumed you were using python...)

Another update: adding \s* before the first capture group, and after the last would filter out those indents/spaces.

\s*?(.+?)([\n\r]+)(.+?[.\?!]+)\s*?

Comment: Thanks for this. To reference the match groups do I just use \1 \3 in the replace part of the find/replace tool? I've tried that on TextMate and TextSoap and they just stick "\1 \3" into the text.

Comment: Using the example text I have now provided, this expression seems to be finding genuine CRs as opposed to the mid-sentence ones. Any ideas?

Comment: Typically this is how it works, but I don't know if you application supports this standard...  If you're having trouble maybe try: ([\n\r]+?) for the center match group.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a [lookbehind assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
s/(?<![.!?]"?)\n/ /
```

(note I think you want to replace with a space, or maybe two spaces, or it will look funny).

You might also be able to get backreferences to work instead.

Comment: Thank you. Textmate tells me this expression is invalid. TextSoap finds no instances based on this expression. Perhaps the example I have posted helps?

Comment: BBEdit also generates an error, specifically: "lookbehind assertion is not fixed length "

Comment: Hmm... yeah, seems like there are a lot of different regex implementations with a lot of different quirks. The syntax is very different in vim, but I did get it to do exactly the right thing there (syntax was `%s/\([.!?]"\?\)\@<!\n/ /`)